# Employing Ubuntu webapps integration on wordpress site

Tags: unity, webapps, wordpress

How can I integrate unity webapps on my self hosted Wordpress site. Locally  I am getting the quicklist options but is there a way using it will be prompt for integration with the unity like Gmail or other websites?

Answer (score 0):

See this page: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-13.04/javascript/unity-webapps/
It tells you about the API which powers unity web apps. BTW most of the existing supported apps exist because of the Ubuntu team putting them in, not because of developers of the website using the API.